# Ng-if Condition View not updating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When I change value in "select box" (ex 10 20 30 etc) it calls Api and giving 20 (select box value) records. I'm getting 20 records but in UI it showing first 10 records only it's not showing 20 records because the table with ng-if condition. outside ng-if it displaying 20 records but I need that ng-if condition. How can I solve this problem

```js
$scope.countperpage = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]; 
            var range = [];
            $scope.numOfPage = 0;
            $scope.Detailchangevalue = function(Detailspage) {
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.entriespage = Detailspage;
                $scope.filterObj = {
                    boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                    pagecountrequired: 'y',
                    currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                    pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                };
                e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.errors) {
                        console.log('Error');
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                        $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                        var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                        var startPage = 1;
                        if (totalPage > 10) {
                            totalPage = 10;
                        }
                        range = [];
                        for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                            range.push(i);
                        }
                        $scope.numOfPage = range;
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.getDetailrecords = function() {
                $scope.Detailloader = true; // Detail Loader
                $scope.filterObj = {
                    boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                    pagecountrequired: 'y',
                    currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                    pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                };
                e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {

                    if (result.errors) {
                        var translateObj = $filter('translate');
                        var translateCaption = translateObj(result.errors.status);
                        alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage(translateCaption);
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                    } else {

                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                        $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                        $scope.Detailloader = false;
                        var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        var totalPageTemp = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                        var currentPage = $scope.currentPage;
                        var startPage = 1;
                        if (totalPage > 10) {
                            totalPage = 10;
                            if (currentPage > 6) {
                                totalPage = totalPage + (currentPage - 6);
                                startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                if (totalPageTemp > totalPage) {
                                    startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);

                                } else {
                                    totalPage = totalPageTemp;
                                    startPage = totalPageTemp - 10;
                                    //startPage=1+(currentPage-6);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        range = [];
                        for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                            range.push(i);
                        }
                        $scope.numOfPage = range;
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.getDetailrecords();
            $scope.getDetailrecordsByPagination = function(currentPage) {
                //alert($scope.currentPage);
                $scope.Detailloader = true;
                if (currentPage !== '') {
                    var tol = parseInt($scope.totalPage);
                    if (parseInt(currentPage) > tol) {
                        alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage('Invalid page number');
                        // alert('Invalid page number');
                        //$scope.currentPage=$scope.totalPage;
                        $scope.currentPage = '';
                    } else {
                        $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
                        $scope.filterObj = {
                            boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                            pagecountrequired: 'y',
                            currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                            pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                        };
                        e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {
                            if (result.errors) {
                                var translateObj = $filter('translate');
                                var translateCaption = translateObj(result.errors.status);
                                alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage(translateCaption);
                                $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                                $scope.Detailloader = false;
                            } else {
                                $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                                $scope.Detailloader = false;
                                $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                                var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                                var totalPageTemp = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                                $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                                var startPage = 1;
                                if (totalPage > 10) {
                                    totalPage = 10;
                                    if (currentPage > 6) {
                                        totalPage = totalPage + (currentPage - 6);
                                        startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                        if (totalPageTemp > totalPage) {
                                            startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                            //console.log('ok '+startPage);
                                        } else {
                                            totalPage = totalPageTemp;
                                            startPage = totalPageTemp - 10;
                                            //startPage=1+(currentPage-6);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                range = [];
                                for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                                    range.push(i);
                                }
                                $scope.numOfPage = range;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
```

```html
<div class="row e2e-details-scroll" ng-class="{'e2e-norecord-space': errorDetailMsg == true}">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table ng-if="!!DetailDetails" class="table table-bordered" id="e2e-detailsTable" datatable="ng" dt-options="configOption">
                            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                <tr class="tableHeading" ng-repeat="data in DetailDetails.DATA | limitTo: 1">
                                    <th class="detaildetalis-heading" table-filter tablename="e2e-detailsTable" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data "> {{"MESSAGE."+ key | translate}} </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="data in DetailDetails.DATA">
                                    <td class="detaildetalis-records" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data"> {{ value }} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- .Table End -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col-md-12 End -->
                </div>
                <!-- 2.row End -->
                <div class="row e2e-j-pagination" ng-class="{'e2e-norecord-space': errorDetailMsg == true}">
                    <div ng-show="!errorDetailMsg">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="import-table-pagination">
                                    <div class="pagination float-left"> <a ng-class="{active: i == currentPage}" href="#" ng-repeat="i in numOfPage" ng-click="getDetailrecordsByPagination(i)">{{i}}</a> </div>
                                    <div class="goto-page">
                                        <lable> Go to page </lable>
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentPage" aria-invalid="false" ng-change="getDetailrecordsByPagination(currentPage)" /> </div>
                                    <div class="pagination-per-page">
                                        <lable>Entries per page </lable>
                                        <div class="selectParent-e2e-shipment pagination-select-container">
                                            <select ng-options="a for a in countperpage" ng-model="entriespage" ng-change="Detailchangevalue(entriespage)"> </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 3.row End -->
                </div>
```

```js
$scope.countperpage = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
            var range = [];
            $scope.numOfPage = 0;
            $scope.Detailchangevalue = function(Detailspage) {
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.entriespage = Detailspage;
                $scope.filterObj = {
                    boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                    pagecountrequired: 'y',
                    currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                    pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                };
                e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.errors) {
                        console.log('Error');
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                        $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                        var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                        var startPage = 1;
                        if (totalPage > 10) {
                            totalPage = 10;
                        }
                        range = [];
                        for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                            range.push(i);
                        }
                        $scope.numOfPage = range;
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.getDetailrecords = function() {
                $scope.Detailloader = true; // Detail Loader
                $scope.filterObj = {
                    boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                    pagecountrequired: 'y',
                    currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                    pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                };
                e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {

                    if (result.errors) {
                        var translateObj = $filter('translate');
                        var translateCaption = translateObj(result.errors.status);
                        alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage(translateCaption);
                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                    } else {

                        $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                        $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                        $scope.Detailloader = false;
                        var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        var totalPageTemp = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                        $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                        var currentPage = $scope.currentPage;
                        var startPage = 1;
                        if (totalPage > 10) {
                            totalPage = 10;
                            if (currentPage > 6) {
                                totalPage = totalPage + (currentPage - 6);
                                startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                if (totalPageTemp > totalPage) {
                                    startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);

                                } else {
                                    totalPage = totalPageTemp;
                                    startPage = totalPageTemp - 10;
                                    //startPage=1+(currentPage-6);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        range = [];
                        for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                            range.push(i);
                        }
                        $scope.numOfPage = range;
                    }
                });
            };
            $scope.getDetailrecords();
            $scope.getDetailrecordsByPagination = function(currentPage) {
                //alert($scope.currentPage);
                $scope.Detailloader = true;
                if (currentPage !== '') {
                    var tol = parseInt($scope.totalPage);
                    if (parseInt(currentPage) > tol) {
                        alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage('Invalid page number');
                        // alert('Invalid page number');
                        //$scope.currentPage=$scope.totalPage;
                        $scope.currentPage = '';
                    } else {
                        $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
                        $scope.filterObj = {
                            boxlevelind: $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter,
                            pagecountrequired: 'y',
                            currentpagenumber: $scope.currentPage,
                            pagesize: $scope.entriespage
                        };
                        e2eservice.getDetailrecords($scope.filterObj, $rootScope.DetailsnameFilter, $rootScope.DetailsboxFilter, $scope.type1).then(function(result) {
                            if (result.errors) {
                                var translateObj = $filter('translate');
                                var translateCaption = translateObj(result.errors.status);
                                alertpopupservice.setErrorMessage(translateCaption);
                                $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                                $scope.Detailloader = false;
                            } else {
                                $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                                $scope.Detailloader = false;
                                $scope.DetailDetails = result;
                                var totalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                                var totalPageTemp = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                                $scope.totalPage = totalPage;
                                var startPage = 1;
                                if (totalPage > 10) {
                                    totalPage = 10;
                                    if (currentPage > 6) {
                                        totalPage = totalPage + (currentPage - 6);
                                        startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                        if (totalPageTemp > totalPage) {
                                            startPage = 1 + (currentPage - 6);
                                            //console.log('ok '+startPage);
                                        } else {
                                            totalPage = totalPageTemp;
                                            startPage = totalPageTemp - 10;
                                            //startPage=1+(currentPage-6);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                range = [];
                                for (var i = startPage; i <= totalPage; i++) {
                                    range.push(i);
                                }
                                $scope.numOfPage = range;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
```

```html
<div class="row e2e-details-scroll" ng-class="{'e2e-norecord-space': errorDetailMsg == true}">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table ng-if="!!DetailDetails" class="table table-bordered" id="e2e-detailsTable" datatable="ng" dt-options="configOption">
                            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                <tr class="tableHeading" ng-repeat="data in DetailDetails.DATA | limitTo: 1">
                                    <th class="detaildetalis-heading" table-filter tablename="e2e-detailsTable" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data "> {{"MESSAGE."+ key | translate}} </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="data in DetailDetails.DATA">
                                    <td class="detaildetalis-records" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data"> {{ value }} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- .Table End -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col-md-12 End -->
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm not able to find changes

Comment: I am not sure that the ng-if condition is your problem - 

Why are you setting totalPage = 10 if totalPage > 10? That may be why you only see 10 records.

Also in your ng-if you have two "!!" marks in your condition which doesn't seem right? If DetailDetails is not, not true! I.E if it is true?

Comment: !!DetailDetails == DetailDetails  (Both same)

Comment: I'm getting 20 records  but not able to show in UI(it's not updating) If I remove ng if then it's working fine. but I need ng-if condition. totalPage = 10 this is not a problem.

Comment: The ng-if condition is controlling the display of the entire table. So I don't see how removing it would make it show 20 rows? From the look of your code the table is either there or not there.  If you can provide an example on pluncker or jsfiddle I can take a look at what you mean.